# spring jpa using page on a *ToMany field

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

In a relation like seller-client, one seller has more than one client and vice versa. If I want to get out all clients for a seller, and because there are too many, so I want to make it pageable no matter in query or on the result (I think paging happens at query would be better). How to do it? I have already tried directly make a pageable query but failed.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "SellerClient", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "sellerId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "clientId") })
private List<Client> clients;
```

And this is my query:

```
Page<Client> clients = sellerRepository.findClientsByMobile(pageable, "seller's mobile");
```

Answer (score 0):

`sellerRepository` should fetch only `Seller` objects. 
You have to create `ClientRepository` (assuming that ID is `String`)

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, String> {

    Page<Client> findAllByMobile(String mobile, Pageable pageable);

}
```